# CSS specificity not working as expected in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, css-selectors

After reading **[6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)** what I expected to happen and what actually is happening seems to contradict. It is obvious that I am understanding it wrong. If someone could give me a brief explanation of why I am wrong on this 1 point and how I can work around it, that would be great.

```
/* opt.css */
#opt input[type="text"] { width: 200px; }
#tok { width: 300px; }

/* opt.html */
<div id="opt"><input id="tok" type="text" /></div>
```

I was expecting, since `#tok` is **more** specific than `#opt input[type="text"]` the width of the input box would be 300px, but its 200px.

```
#opt input[type="text"]  /* a=0 b=0 c=1 d=1 -> specificity = 0,0,1,1 */
#tok                     /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
```

I can see by Chrome Inspector that the 200px is getting the priority and that 300 is crossed out, so my understanding of specificity is wrong. I just don't understand how I am getting this wrong. Does `b` not override `c` and `d`?

Also how to work around this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#tok` is less specific than `#opt input[type="text"]`:

```
#tok                     /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=0 -> specificity = 0,1,0,0 */
#opt input[type="text"]  /* a=0 b=1 c=0 d=1 -> specificity = 0,1,0,1 */
```

`b` = number of ids
`c` = number of attributes and pseudo-classes 
`d` = number of element names and pseudo-elements

Comment: but #opt is #tok's parent, not #tok, so surely that part would not apply only the input[type="text"]??

Comment: yes but as you see above you have the same number of ids in both selectors but as you have used an element selector too in the `#opt input` it is more specific than just #tok, therefore that rule will take precedence

Comment: And to the 2nd part of the question, How do I work around that?

Comment: just use `#opt #tok {width:300px}` as this has two ids it will be more specific that `#opt input`

Comment: [This article may help](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), it has a good explanation of the calculations near the bottom

Comment: Thank you, I have read through this and explains exactly as you have. I just think maybe there should be a difference between 'Direct ID' and 'any ID'.. Since #tok is the ID of the actual item I want to use and #opt is just an ID of the parent. Though, its not like I am going to be able to change w3c's standards..

Comment: @WORMSS: You're not alone. Even the CSSWG folks agree that the specificity system is broken for the modern web.